# R: How to unTag the Sentence, after tagged by tagPOS

Tags: regex, r, opennlp

I have tagged part of Speech to an string using **tagPOS**
Now I want to **unTag** the string and get back as it was previous.

```
library(openNLP)
str <- "this is the a demo string. Which is used to show tagPOS capability.
And I want to untagged the tagged sentence.
Kindly help to do this."
tagged_str <-  tagPOS(str)
print(tagged_str)
```

**Output:**

"this/DT is/VBZ the/DT a/DT demo/NN string./NN Which/WDT is/VBZ used/VBN to/TO show/VB tagPOS/NNS capability./.
And/CC I/PRP want/VBP to/TO untagged/VB the/DT tagged/JJ sentence./NN Kindly/RB help/VB to/TO do/VB this./."

**Desired Output:**

this is the a demo string. Which is used to show tagPOS capability.
    And I want to untagged the tagged sentence.
    Kindly help to do this."

Comment: Why not to copy it before tagging?

Comment: They have the copy with `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(tagged_str, "/|\\s"), "[", c(TRUE, FALSE)), collapse = " ")
```

**Edit:**

Per your new request.  A bit different approach:

```
paste(unlist(strsplit(tagged_str, "/[[:upper:]]*\\s|/\\.")), collapse = " ")
```

Comment: But @Tyler Rinker, this will also exclude the string containing optional word like 'his/her', 'yes/no', etc.
Any suggestion for that.